# How to convert to an Object by handling null inputs

Tags: java, lombok

How to convert to an Object by handling null inputs, is there a way to check for null inputs and return null without writing the if check for null;

```
public static Image convert(SyndImage syndImage) {
    return Image.builder()
        .title(syndImage.getTitle())
        .url(syndImage.getUrl())
        .build();
}
```

Comment: How about the use the Optional  to pack your object ，the Optional class is supported after Java8

Comment: syndImage itself is null, how to handle it elegantly and return null

Comment: String s = null;
String trim = Optional.ofNullable(s).orElse("").trim();

Comment: Like the up code , if don't use the Optional,it may say NullPointException,but like the code ,it can replace the empty object to a default object to avoid the NullPoint

Comment: syndImage is null and its not a string

Comment: The string can replace by your syndImage ... I don't defined a object like syndImage ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use requireNonNullElse() like this:

```
return Image.builder()
.title(Objects.requireNonNullElse(syndImage.getTitle(), "Default Title"))
.url(Objects.requireNonNullElse(syndImage.getUrl(), "Default URL"))
.build();
```

Comment: I don't want to build the object if input is null and just return null

Comment: oh then this comes to mind 'return syndImage == null ? null : return Image.builder()...'

Comment: @user352290 Your title and question are not clear. They could use some editing.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the builder

[You commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77072135/how-to-convert-to-an-object-by-handling-null-inputs/77073836#comment135870230_77072321):

> I don't want to build the object if input is null and just return null

Sounds like a job for your Builder. That is one purpose of a builder: Verify inputs before constructing an object.

So if you don't like one of the inputs (`null`, whatever), have `Image.builder().….build()` return `null`.

Or better, have it return an empty [`Optional< Image >`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) object. The point of `Optional` is to flag to the calling programmer that a null value is a legitimate result.

```java
public static Optional< Image > convert(SyndImage syndImage) {
    return Image.builder()
        .title(syndImage.getTitle())
        .url(syndImage.getUrl())
        .build();
}
```

Inside your builder code:

```java
if ( Objects.isNull( url ) ) { return Optional.empty() ; }
```

The calling code checks to see if they received an `Image` object in the payload.

```java
if( optionalImage.isPresent() ) { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have limitations to update existing builder or refactor to optional return for getImage,you could implement as below

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

@Data
class SyndImage{
    String title;
    String url;

    public SyndImage(String title, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public SyndImage(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public SyndImage() {

    }
}
class Image{}
public class OptionalUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Assertions.assertNull(getImage(new SyndImage()));//null fields
        //SyndImage allFileds = new SyndImage("MyTitle1", "Url1");
        Assertions.assertNotNull(getImage(new SyndImage("MyTitle1", "Url1")));//all fields

        //SyndImage title = new SyndImage("Title");
        Assertions.assertNull(getImage(new SyndImage("Title")));//only title field is available
        
        Assertions.assertNull(getImage(null));//null fields
        
    }

    private static Image getImage(SyndImage syndImage) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(syndImage)
                .filter(sImage-> Objects.nonNull(sImage.getTitle()))//if field checks are also required
                .filter(sImage->Objects.nonNull(sImage.getUrl()))
                .map(sImage->iamgeBuilderMethod(sImage))
                .orElse(null);//this is generally not recommended
    }

    private static Image iamgeBuilderMethod(SyndImage sImage) {
       /* return Image.builder()
                .title(syndImage.getTitle())
                .url(syndImage.getUrl())
                .build();*/
        System.out.println("Image created");
        return new Image();//this will be your existing convert method
    }
}
```